# Ruby scan/gets until EOF

Tags: ruby, eof

I want to scan unknown number of lines till all the lines are scanned. How do I do that in ruby?

For ex:

```
put returns between paragraphs

for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

_italic_ or **bold**
```

The input is not from a 'file' but through the STDIN.

Comment: you mean you are getting unknown number of lines as input via keyboard? somewhat like STDIN in some coding competitions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`IO#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-read) (without `length` argument, it reads until EOF)

```
lines = STDIN.read
```

---

or use [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) with `nil` as argument:

```
lines = gets(nil)
```

To denote EOF, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Unix) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (Windows).

Comment: When doing gets(nil), always check the return value to see if it's nil, which is what's returned when stdin is an empty file. Also, gets(nil) by default reads from files named on the command line, which is not normally what you want, so typically you'd want to do $stdin.gets(nil).

Answer (score 15):

Many ways to do that in ruby.
Most usually, you're gonna wanna process one line at a time, which you can do, for example, with

```
while line=gets
end
```

or

```
STDIN.each_line do |line|
end
```

or by running ruby with the `-n` switch, for example, which implies one of the above loops (line is being saved into `$_` in each iteration, and you can add`BEGIN{}`, and `END{}`, just like in `awk`—this is really good for one-liners).

I wouldn't do `STDIN.read`, though, as that will read the whole file into memory at once (which may be bad, if the file is really big.)